# C# Web Api 2 How to redirect request to default controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a situation where most of the requests will be processed with dedicated controllers.

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DataApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "default"
            }
    );
```

But there may be a situation where no `controller` will be found based on URL. Like `api/this_controller_is_not_exists/GetStatus`.

How can I redirect those requests to default controller called `default` and process this request using action inside default controller?
Valid requests for default controller would look like `api/default/GetStatus`.

The route will be no much different for valid and invalid request.
Valid:

```
'api/this_controller_exist/GetStatus'
```

Invalid:

```
'api/this_controller_not_exists/GetStatus'
```

Comment: What does the defaultController do?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : It contains defaults actions where 'this_controller_not_exists' can be used as a parameter to further processing with default logic.

Comment: As a workaround you can handle 404 error and redirect to default controller manually

Comment: You can handle this by writing custom error handler which will redirect to default controller if passed controller is not found. You can also write custom controller factory which will inject DefaultController if the passed controller is not passed. But I don't understand why you need this feature. You are actually opening up your API for attack where any URL targeting to your API domain will go to default controller and return response. This can lead to DOS attack.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a default route mapping named `default` and if your controller does really exists then it will automatically map the request to your controller `this_controller_exist` cause after the requested URI passes through `RouteData` it will be feeded to `HttpControllerSelector` which will try to get all the controller in your API project inherits from `ApiController` using reflection. Thus if the controller in your question does really exists and derives from `ApiController` then it won't be an issue provided you have a default route mapping in `WebApiConfig` else if not found it will resort to IIS resource handling which will end up throwing a 404 `resource not found` error.

Comment: Thanks, you actually pointed me a solution. As you said it should work by default with `Default controller` I've started to looking why it's not working for me. I found that my `default controller class` cannot be an `abstract` `class`. So instead of `abstract DefaultClass : ApiController` I am using now `DefaultClass : MyBaseClass` where `MyBaseClass` is  `abstract MyBaseClass : ApiController`.